# Connection bug JTextfield (Code Added)

Tags: java, sql-server, static, jtextfield

I have the following methods: 
make connection

```
            try {
                kc = ArchiveConnectionHandler.makeMSSQLConnection(
                        MSSQLDriver, 
                        MSSQLconnString, 
                        guiValues.get(1),
                        guiValues.get(2), 
                        guiValues.get(3), 
                        guiValues.get(4));

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame("succes");

                kc.close();

            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SQLException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame("error"), 
                        "Error");
            }
```

Connection method

```
public static java.sql.Connection makeMSSQLArchConnection(String driver, String connectionString, String user, String pass, String ipaddress, String port)  
        throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException
{
    if(MSArchiveConnection == null)
    {
        Class.forName(driver);
        MSArchiveConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString + "://" + ipaddress + ":" + port, user, pass);
        if(MSArchiveConnection != null)
        {
            System.out.println("MSArchiveConnection!");
        }
    }
    return MSArchiveConnection;
}
```

Method for sending GUI values

```
public List<String> getGuiValues(){

    List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
    values.add(btngrp.getSelection().getActionCommand());
    values.add(kanaUsernameTf.getText());
    values.add(kanaPasswordTf.getText());
    values.add(kanaIpAdressTf.getText());
    values.add(KanaPortTf.getText());
    values.add(archiveUsernameTf.getText());
    values.add(archivePasswordTf.getText());
    values.add(archiveIpAdressTf.getText());
    values.add(archivePortTf.getText());
    values.add(archiveDbNameTf.getText());
    values.add(btngrp2.getSelection().getActionCommand());
    values.add(archiveDateTf.getText());
    values.add(sessionAmountTf.getText());
    values.add(xmlLocation.getText());
    values.add(oldAttachtmentLoc.getText());
    values.add(newAttachmentLoc.getText());

    return values;  
}
```

I have a method In a GUI class that drops user input in a list.
This list is used to make a connection with a MSSQL database.
This Connection is made using a static method.

Here is my problem, when I click the button the connection is not remade. So when I empty all the fields and want to retest the connection, the test is still succesful. Can someone explain this to me.

**EDIT**

```
package com.kahuna.jkram.userinterface;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import com.kahuna.jkram.utils.ArchiveConnectionHandler;

public class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener {

    private ArchiveUserInterface ui;

    public ButtonHandler(ArchiveUserInterface ui){

        this.ui = ui;

        for(JButton button : ui.getButtons())
        {
            button.addActionListener(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        String MSSQLDriver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";
        List<String> guiValues = ui.getGuiValues();
        String MSSQLconnString = "jdbc:sqlserver";
        String action = e.getActionCommand();

        Connection kc = null;

        if(action.equals("kanaTest"))
        {
            if(guiValues.get(0).equals("MSSQL"))
            {

                try {
                    kc = ArchiveConnectionHandler.makeMSSQLConnection(
                            MSSQLDriver, 
                            MSSQLconnString, 
                            guiValues.get(1),
                            guiValues.get(2), 
                            guiValues.get(3), 
                            guiValues.get(4));

                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame("Database connectie test."), 
                            "De databaseverbinding is succesvol getest.");

                    kc.close();


                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (SQLException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame("SQL Fout"), 
                            "Er is een databasefout opgetreden, controleer de verbinding");
                }
            }
        }
        else if(action.equals("archiveTest"))
        {
            try {
                Connection ac = ArchiveConnectionHandler.makeMSSQLArchConnection(
                        MSSQLDriver, 
                        MSSQLconnString, 
                        guiValues.get(5), 
                        guiValues.get(6), 
                        guiValues.get(7), 
                        guiValues.get(8));

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame("Database connectie test."), 
                        "De databaseverbinding is succesvol getest.");
                ac.close();
                System.out.println(ac.isClosed());

            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SQLException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame("SQL Fout"), 
                        "Er is een databasefout opgetreden, controleer de verbinding");
            }
        }
        else if(action.equals("saveSettings"))
        {
            System.out.println("Save Settings");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the first time connection made? If so how can you tell that the connection is not remade?

Comment: Every time I click the button, I retest the connection with the entered values. Every time I call the static method to make the connection, the method prints MSArchiveConnection. But this messages only apears when I click the button for the first time. After that I don't see the message.

Comment: You don't keep a static reference right? Can you post the complete code?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem, thanks for pointing me in the right direction.
I changed the method from static to non-static.